# Embedded applet not running

Tags: java, applet

For my current project I need to solve an issue on embedded applet.

Here is the code which suddenly stopped running:

```html
<applet code="DrawApplet.class" codebase="draw/"
    width=125 height=150 id=
   <PARAM NAME="BAH" VALUE="">
   <PARAM NAME="id" VALUE="">
   <PARAM NAME="type" VALUE="Sig">
   <PARAM NAME="server" VALUE="https://www.sample.com">
   <PARAM NAME="java_arguments" VALUE="-Djnlp.packEnabled=false">
 </applet>
```

I have not much idea on Java but having some basic knowledge. Can anyone please figure out the reason?

Comment: one of the reasons might be: support for applets has been shut down. forget about applets if you want a functioning application

Comment: @Stultuske Can you please help me how this <applet> script can be converted into <object> or suggest if you have any alternate solution

Comment: re-write the entire thing. stop using applets, and use a different technology. the problem is that browsers no longer support applets, and those that still do, will soon (enough) drop support

Comment: I agree with @Stultuske, right up to the *"soon (enough)"* - they should have been deprecated & dropped support years ago. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). BTW - the opening `applet` element was never closed with a `>`.